# will be vs. gonna be

Tags: tense

*1. I wonder who is gonna be the new actor director XY is gonna shoot with.*

*2. I wonder who is gonna be the new actor director XY will shoot with.*

*3. I wonder who will be the new actor director XY is gonna shoot with.*

*4. I wonder who will be the new actor director XY will shoot with.*

Can you tell me which sentence related to the future is the most suitable?

Comment: *Whom* and pied piping are exceedingly formal, while *gonna* is eye dialect for an informal contraction of *going to*.  They clash.  A lot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have changed it. Does it sound already more natural?

Comment: @bart-leby "With who" is not a valid phrase grammatically. "With" is a preposition, so the object must be of the object form, *whom*. Snailboat is correct in that it makes the sentence sound bizarre, but you should probably re-write the sentence instead of creating more errors.

Comment: The better ordering would be "I wonder who [is gonna/will be] the new actor director XY is gonna shoot with". This removes the ambiguity of being shot (with a camera) vs being shot (with a gun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Choice #1 is informal, but self-consistent.**  I would expect to hear it in ordinary conversation, or on a "gushy" pop-culture television show or podcast.

> 1a. I wonder who is gonna be the new actor director XY is gonna shoot with.

I would expect to hear contractions instead of the word "is":

> 1b. I wonder who's gonna be the new actor director XY's gonna shoot with.

Quotes #1a and #1b might be transcribed as:

> 1c. I wonder who is going to be the new actor director XY is going to shoot with.

In order to avoid making speakers sound "dumb", "incoherent", or "uneducated", transcribers often spell out contractions.  For example, "who's" may become "who is", and "gonna" may become "going to".  This makes the written version of the speech more formal than the spoken version.  It also perpetuates the myth that educated people consistently use formal speech.

**Choice #4 is formal, and also self-consistent:**

> 4. I wonder who will be the new actor director XY will shoot with.

**Choices #2 and #3 are inconsistent.**  I would not expect to hear them in either a formal or an informal context.

Comment: As @tkp points out, saying "director" immediately after "new actor" is confusing.  Inserting a "that" can help:  "I wonder who's gonna be the new actor that director XY's gonna shoot with."  In this context, the audience might know that XY is a director, so the example might omit the word "director":  "I wonder who's gonna be the new actor that Spielberg's gonna shoot with?"

Answer (score -1):

I'd choose a fifth:

*5. I wonder who will be the new actor with whom director XY will shoot.*

Although "don't end with a preposition" is often lame advice, sometimes doing so can make things clearer. Here it helps by breaking up that clumsy *"new actor director XY".*

Comment: This choice sounds completely unnatural to my (American) ear.

Comment: Thee days it would sound unnatural (specifically, old-fashioned) to most native speakers. I do it only on occasion to control the order of parts of a sentence, and even when that's needed there are usually better ways to do it. Of course this demands a mention of the old joke: Young American Rhodes scholar gets lost at Oxford and asks a passing don, "Excuse me. Can you tell me where the library's at?" Snooty don replies "My dear chap! One must never end one's sentence with a preposition!" American replies. "My apologies. Can you tell me where the library's at, asshole?"